# Algorithms for Cyrillic encryption

Tags: encryption, encoding

I am working on a cryptography application which is to be used in my country. I tried looking up to see if there are any algorithms that support the Cyrillic alphabet, but I found none. Do you know of any? Can mainstream algorithms (Like AES) work with Cyrillic letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Can AES work with Cyrillic letters?**

No, AES is a [*block cipher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) that can only operate on blocks of 16 bytes. AES may be securily used within a [*mode of operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) to operate on plaintext of any bit/byte size.

So you only have to encode your Cyrillic letters to any bit or byte encoding. Unicode - which designates code points to a huge range of characters - specifies the most likely candicate: UTF-8 encoding.

UTF-8 is identical to ASCII for any code points up to 127. After that it uses more bytes depending on the value of the code point; higher code points require more bytes.

---

So you follow these steps for encryption:

- character encode your Cyrillic text in UTF-8, results in the plaintext
- encrypt the plaintext, results in the ciphertext
- possibly encode the ciphertext using base 64, resulting in encoded ciphertext

and for decryption:

- possibly decode the encoded ciphertext using base 64, resulting in the (binary) ciphertext
- decrypt the ciphertext, results in the plaintext
- character decode the plaintext, results in your Cyrillic text

---

Notes:

- for modern ciphers, plaintext and ciphertext are *binary* despite their name;
- character encoding (e.g. UTF-8) converts strings of characters to bytes;
- encoding (e.g. base 64) converts bytes to printable characters;
- for larger text you may want to look into streaming, all of the above can be accomplished using streams as well;
- if you want to send something you also need an authentication tag (MAC or HMAC) over the ciphertext.

Answer (score 11):

Modern cryptographic algorithms are specified in terms of **bytes** or even bits, not *characters*.
Whether the data you encrypt happens to represent latin or cyrillic letters or pictures or audio data or anything else does not matter at all to an encryption algorithm; all it ever sees is a bunch of bytes.

What this means in practice is: You have to fix some **encoding** ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is very common nowadays) to translate your characters to a string of bytes which can then be processed by any cryptographic implementation as usual.

Comment: So does that mean that I can convert the bytes to UTF-8 and work with them just as I would with ASCII? Would I end up with the same result (as my code already works with ASCII bytes)? For example, let's take AES, wouldn't UTF-8 characters be too big to have representations in the S-box matrix?

Comment: @Elhitch Your terminology seems a bit off: UTF-8 encodes *Unicode characters* to *bytes*. AES encrypts *bytes* to *bytes*. If you encode your *Unicode string* to a string of *bytes* using UTF-8 before applying AES, that should work, unless you do strange things to the bytes besides encrypting. Indeed, the set of *Unicode characters* is too large to be encoded into a single byte per character: That is why UTF-8 encodes most non-ASCII characters to more than one single byte. For instance, UTF-8 encodes the cyrillic *character* ф to the *bytes* `d1 84`.

Answer (score 1):

Modern cryptographic algorithms work on strings of bits, independently of how such strings are interpreted in any specific application.